# Matlab coder - Expected a scalar. Non-scalars are not supported in IF or WHILE

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

I have the following matlab code
v is an array of one dimention.

```
v = getV(x,y,z);
if isempty(v)
    fail_code = 1;
elseif max(v) <= vmax % <============== error is here
    fail_code = 0;
    vplus = max(v);
else
    vplus = vmax;
end
```

this working fine, however when I try to convert it into a c code in matlab coder I get the following error:
`Expected a scalar. Non-scalars are not supported in IF or WHILE statements, or with logical operators. Instead, use ALL to convert matrix logicals to their scalar equivalents.`

I am not fully familiar with matlab data types, maybe why I am missing something.

Comment: what does `size(v)` give you? `size(max(v))`? Obviously, the second expression isn't a scaler. Off the top of my head, it's possible that `v` is a cell array or has leading singleton dimensions. You also have a syntax error on that line. Matlab uses `elif` not elseif. So that may be throwing mlint for a loop too. THEN you have a potential logic error. `vplus` is either going to be a scaler or an array depending on the contents of `v`. You probably meant `vplus=max(v)`

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: no, MATLAB does use `elseif` (see the doc at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/if.html), so there's no syntax error on that line. However, it would be good to check `size(v)` and `size(max(v))` as suggested.

Comment: yes I had some changes because it is a work related project, what inside the condition procedures were changed. and yes it should be max(v). however, this coder doesnt convert it because it doesnt know the dimension of what max is returning i think! vmax is a single value, and max dimension is "1 x :?" and size of v is 1X1 up to 1X3, initialized inside getV to v = []

Comment: size(v) = 1x2 and size(max(v)) was also 1x2

Comment: You could test if `elseif max(v) <= 1`? works - this way you could make sure whether vmax of max(v) is the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would put:

```
elseif all(max(v) <= vmax)
```

or

```
elseif max(v(:)) <= vmax
```

In MATLAB, `if test` can pass even if `test` is not a scalar. If `test` is an array of logicals, it will pass if all the elements are non-zero.

However, that is not supported by MATLAB Coder when converting to C. So, you would need to explicitly ensure that you get a scalar, either by inserting an `all`, or comparing `v` to its maximum as a vector.

Answer (score 2):

Why not follow the advice within the error-message and try:

`elseif all(max(v) <= vmax)`

In your special case the `all()` might be superfluous, but I assume that the coder tries to respect the possibility that the comparison **could** in principle result in an array.

Comment: all function was suggested, however it just return zeros or ones

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to test for `v` being a vector with `isvector`.

```
if isvector(v)
  %true case
  vplus = max(v); % returns a scalar
  vplus(vplus>= vmax) = vmax;
else
  %false case (matrix)
  error('something wrong - v dimension');
end
```

Comment: it was a mixed dimension issue, so kinda like a vector in different dimension

Answer (score 1):

the dimension get mixed up, the compiler telling me to use `all` function, however 
I did the following, and it was the fix

```
v = v(:);
```

before passing it to max, and all solved

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem since I have a variable with flexible size as

```
if a==b
c = 1;
else
c = [1,1]
end
```

To solve this problem, I have to define `c` in advance as `[0,0]`.

It seems that in `Matlab Coder` the flexible size is not supported.